# How to call AWS lambda function from function URL?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, http, aws-lambda

Below is my lambda function in Python

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    current_version = "1.2.10"

    app_version = event['app_version']

    if app_version == current_version:
        message = True
    else:
        message = False
    
    response = {'updateReq': message}
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(response)
    }
```

It works fine while i test it in AWS console. Then I created a function URL and test it with Insomnia. It show error of "InternalServerError".
Below is my request body, method:POST

```
{
    "app_version":"1.1.0"
}
```

Any possible reason?

Edit: added error log from CloudWatch [LOG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNd8T.png)

```
[ERROR] KeyError: 'app_version'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 15, in lambda_handler
    app_version = event['app_version']
```

Comment: What does CloudWatch Logs show for the execution of the function, or is the function never actually invoked? Can you add some debug statements to identify where the function gets up to?

Comment: Log the entire event and see that the request body is not on the top level.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein added cloudwatch log

Comment: @luk2302 added cloudwatch log

Comment: Add a `print(event)` statement at the start of the function to see what it contains.

Answer (score 0):

Lambdas invoked via Function URLs receive an [API Gateway Proxy Integration v2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-integrations-lambda.html#http-api-develop-integrations-lambda.proxy-format) event.  The request body is at `event["body"]`.  It's a string value.  Deserialize the JSON to get at the payload.

```py
body = json.loads(event['body'])

app_version = body['app_version']
```